# Why does Codeigniter set_flashdata() insert wrong information?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, uri

Look at this code:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('prev_page', $this->uri->uri_string());
echo $this->uri->uri_string();
echo $this->session->flashdata('prev_page');
```

When visiting `mywebsite/index.php/home/`

`echo $this->uri->uri_string();` prints `home`

`echo $this->session->flashdata('prev_page');` prints `home/picktype`, a completely different function in the same controller!

The controller functions in question:

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{   
    if($this->input->cookie('disclaimer_seen_token'))
    {
        $this->load->view('home');

    } else {

        redirect('disclaimer'); 
    }

}

public function picktype()
{   
    $this->load->view('picktype');
}

}
```

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Your flashdata has not been updated until you 'redirect' back to another page.

So your  `$this->session->flashdata('prev_page')` is your LAST page before the redirect.

[The docs specifically state:](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

*CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the **next** server request, and are then automatically cleared*

Comment: I know this. I keep refreshing the home page. The output is always the same.

Comment: but where are you 'refreshing' the home page from? i.e. is the home page doing a redirect itself, so you end up looping the flashdata?

Comment: The flashdata isn't being looped. I refresh from the browser - all other page calls (I've got quite a few in my home controller) echo out the uri string and the same uri string as flashdata after  I refresh the page and the values are updated. Only the index function is behaving strangely.